# Classic Asp page error "Error accessing the OLE registry." (permissions, users?)

Tags: iis

I think this has to do with permissions. The authentication for the web app is "Windows Integrated Authentication". I need this because the app depends on the window log in name.

Here's the error.

Error Type:
error '8002801c' 
Error accessing the OLE registry.

/iisHelp/common/500-100.asp, line 154

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IIS are you using?
Maybe you have to add the authenticated users to the IIS_WPG local group

Answer (score 0):

Use an account with higher privilages. It is most likely a permission error.